# Azure Guest OS and SDK compatibility

Tags: .net, azure, sdk, operating-system, virtual-machine

I am trying to find compatible sdk for Azure Guest os 2.26. I found this link but not useful.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee924680.aspx

Does anyone know compatible sdk for above os?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the 2 tables in the link you mentioned, you can see that Guest OS 2.26 belongs to OS Family 2 which supports SDK Version 1.3 and later.

[image]

[image]